# Firefox : Form submit button click does not always carry the form details to the server

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, safari, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to submit a simple form where i need to enter email and click on submit button where email validation is performed in the backend. When i enter email and click on submit button it throws an error "Email is required" although i can see the email is entered by the webdriver. This works absolutely fine in Chrome but fails most times on firefox and Safari.

Below is my html:

```
<div class="test-form">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 divider5050-hr">
                            <span class="or-sperator-hr">OR</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <form class="js-form" action="#" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="m-md-tb text-center">
                                    <h3>Sign up with your email address:</h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Enter your email address </label>
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control js-register-email" maxlength="50" name="email_address" placeholder="e.g. john@example.com" data-bind="value: registerCustomer">
                                </div>
                                <div class="row m-t">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-width--large m-md-tb js-register-submit" id="SignUp" data-bind="click: registerNewCustomer">
                                            Continue
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                            <span>Already have an account?  <a class="underline" href="https://test.test.com/account/login/checkuserexists">Sign in</a></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Below is what i tried to do:

```
waitforvisibilityofElement(email);
email.sendkeys("testemail");
waitforvisibilityofElement(continue); //clicking submit button
continue.click();
```

When i do a click operation on Firefox or Safari i get the error "Email is required" for the email field though i can see email has been entered. I also tried putting Thread.sleep but didn't work. And it works in Chrome without any issues.

I have also tried submitting the form, using javascript click, using sendkeys(keys.return/Enter) but nothing seems to be working consistently. Could someone please help what could be this browser specific issue in Firefox and Safari ?

Comment: What is `email` object in your code? How do you initialise it?

Comment: It is `WebElement` for sure. The problem is... Selenium is such a tool... If I were OP I would add Thread.sleep(2000) before clicking submit. Just for test.

Comment: @Andremoniy @FindBy(id ="email")
 private WebElement email; , Yes it's a webElement

Comment: @amateurCoder this is a very strange way for binding id/named field

Comment: @Pijotrek i tried thread.sleep too but it does not work even after waiting upto 30 seconds. i could see the email entered in the email field by webdriver. it's the click on submit which throws the error "Email is Required".

Comment: @Andremoniy I am using page object model. it doesn't work even if you give the raw way by driver.findElement(). Problem is not with finding webelement but the errors as mentioned in the question.

Comment: There's a possibility that some fancy JS code blocks the output. Did you try yourself with FF/Safari? Please take a look at dev tools console.

Comment: From above html code, we can not predict your outcome properly, it's better if you will provide us site url along with proper details.

Comment: @Pijotrek Seems like you have a point. i can see below logs in console:
i)A Parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script ii)Mixed Content: The page at example.com/account/signup' was loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form which targets an insecure endpoint example.com This endpoint should be made available over a secure connection.

Comment: @JainishKapadia Wish i could but i cannot share the confidential project details here.

Comment: I think the issue is with the format. Try with testemail@xyz.com and lets see if it works.

Comment: @Kapil i tried it still doesn't work. The problem is not with email format as it is working fine in chrome. once webdriver enters  email and fails on submit, i tried to click on submit again manually it's not working that way either but if i change anything in the email entered by webdriver and do a submit it is proceeding to the next page.

Comment: I think Chrome is doing something internally which other browsers are not able to do while reaching out for the validation to the server. May be a timing issue but did use thread.sleep before submitting. Any other ideas are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i am able to resolve my problem with a piece of javascript code which works on Firefox.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
js.executeScript("var e=document.getElementById('email'); e.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); e.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur')); return true;" );
```

I Still have one issue as the above code works with firefox but not on Safari (IPhone- RealDevice).